# Angularjs: ng-click doesn't work inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I'm building a tree-view and each branch is created inside a directive.
The problem is that the event ng-click doesn't work.
This is the directive, the event is at the end of the var myBranch.
The function it calls is inside the controller which the directive "shapetree" element belongs. Anyway also a simple alert doesn't work in that ng-click event.
Can you help me please?

```js
app.directive("shapetree", function() {
  return {
  restrict: "A",
  link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
   
   $scope.$watch(
    function($scope) {
     return $scope.courseCats
    },
    function() {
     ...
     var myBranch = angular.element('<li >'+courseCat+'&nbsp;<span role="button" ng-click="addObl('+idAnagSel+','+idCourseCat+')"></span></li>');
     
     var mainTree = angular.element('#mainTree');
     
     mainTree.append(myBranch);
     
    }
   );
  }
  }
});
```

Comment: Simply said: the reason is because angular does not automatically map ng directives (like ng-click) to manually created DOM. Try to avoid this by  use a template within your directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#template-expanding-directive

Comment: Use the `template` property to define your HTML and pass the `scope` variables to it

Comment: you have to use $compile service, before append your html

Answer (score 1):

Your directive should be something like this:

```
app.directive("shapetree", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<li>{{courseCat}}&nbsp;<span role="button" ng-click="addObl(idAnagSel, idCourseCat)"></span></li>',
        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
            // Just an example to assign the right variables
            $scope.idAnagSel = 'x';
            $scope.idCourseCat = 'y';
            $scope.courseCats = 'z';
            $scope.addObl = function (idAnagSel, idCourseCat) {
                 // Do something
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, in fact in this way it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.directive("shapetree", function($compile) {
  return {
  restrict: "A",
  link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
   
   $scope.$watch(
    function($scope) {
     return $scope.courseCats
    },
    function() {
     ...
     var myBranch = angular.element('<li >'+courseCat+'&nbsp;<span role="button" ng-click="addObl('+idAnagSel+','+idCourseCat+')"></span></li>');
     
     var mainTree = angular.element('#mainTree');
     
compiled = $compile(myBranch);

     mainTree.append(myBranch);
     
compiled($scope);
    }
   );
  }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've supposed that something should have been compiled, but i couldn't find the way. This system too works, now will decide which solution to implement :-)